# "No worry" vs. "No worries"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, expressions, differences, grammatical-number

I'm confused about the use of "No worry" vs. "No worries". Are both of them correct? If so, do they have the same meaning, or do they mean different things? What are the contexts where one vs. the other is used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No worries is an expression seen in Australian/British/New Zealand-English meaning "**do not worry about that".**

> - that's all right
> - sure thing

It is similar to the English **no problem.**

- "No worries" (always plural).         "No problem" (always singular).
- Resource: [No worries-Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_worries)

Opinion: If a speaker would want to refer to several related problems: no problems, should always make sense.

Comment: When was the last time you were in the states? In Chicago, I hear "no worries" at least three times per day.

Answer (score 5):

The correct one is

> No worries

According to wikipedia it originated in Australia (my country).

In Australia, 'mate' often gets added:

> No worries, mate.

In North Queensland,

> Yeah no worries ay.

Alternative forms:

> No worries, bro / sis.
>
> No worries, brother / sister.
>
> No worries, brah.
>
> No worries, eh bro. (Common with New Zealanders)

And other classics:

> No worries, c**t
>
> No wuckin' furries   ('u' said like short a)

Answer (score 4):

"no worry" is not a phrase used in English; perhaps the closest phrase that is not idiomatic might be "don't worry."   But "no worries" is a popular idiom meaning "don't worry" or "it's okay", when used as an answer to "I'm sorry" or "excuse me". As an answer to "how are you?" or "how's it going?" it means "I have no big problems or worries."

Answer (score 2):

"No worry" is generally used to signify the lack of worry, whereas "no worries" is a more idiomatic phrase that could be extended to something like "don't worry about it," and is often used when someone is being apologized to for something and instructing the person not to fret over the matter. Saying "no worry" in this context would probably be understood, but is nonetheless abnormal.